# CSS and Html question

Tags: html, css

I just found a page of [web developer interview questions](http://www.obiwankimberly.com/2010/01/12/web-developer-job-interview-questions/), and I'm not sure what the answers are for two of them. For Q1, I pick answer e. For Q2, I pick answer b, but I'm not sure if there are better ways to do it.

1. Which markup structure is most semantic for a title within a document body, considering that the title may be horizontally centered using a large, bold, red font?

   a. `<h1>This is a Title</h1>`

   b. `<p align="center"><font size="+3"><b>This is a Title</b></font></p>`

   c. `<h1 style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large; text-align:center; color:red;">This is a Title</h1>`

   d. `<title>This is a Title</title>`

   e. `<h1 class="LargeRedBoldCenterHeading">This is a Title</h1>`

   f. `<span class="title">This is a Title</span>`
2. Are each of the following footer markup solutions acceptable? Why or why not? What alternate solution(s) would you propose?

   a. `<div id="footer">`
            `Copyright 2010 My Company | This text is arbitratry.`
         `</div>`

   b. `<div id="footer">`
            `<p>Copyright 2010 My Company | This text is arbitratry.</p>`
         `</div>`

Comment: Q1 looks like a is the winner.....Q2.....still in debate.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer for `1.` is `a` as you should only have one `h1` tag on your page (so a class is probably unnecessary if it's only for the `h1`) and because the class used in `e` is not semantic (e.g. "Title") but instead describes a very particular styling so would be useless if you later changed the way you want to display the title.

In fact you can rule out the other options like this:

- b) Uses `align` attribute, uses a `font` tag, uses a `b` tag (this one is iffy but they would prefer you used `em`), uses a `p` tag for a heading.
- c) Uses inline styles
- d) Uses the `title` element in the `body` to try and render content. This belongs in the `head` and shouldn't display anything on the page anyway even if it was incorrectly and invalidly placed in the `body`.
- e) Uses a class which is poorly named. Classes should describe the meaning of the class (e.g. "EmphasisedHeader", "HelpButton" etc. ) and not how the class is rendered. Think of them as a tag - would you like a `<LargeRedBoldCenterHeading>` tag or an `<EmphasisedHeader>` tag?
- f) Invalid HTML

For question `2.` the answer is trickier. The `p` tag is unnecessary as a `div` is already a block element by default.

In HTML 5 there is a `footer` element for this, and indeed one of the more attractive but abandoned proposals early on was to allow you to name any element you like (perhaps using your own "meta-doctype") and just have them render like a `div` (e.g. you could have an `<adbox>` tag instead of `<div class="adbox">`).

It could probably be argued that they should be in a `<ul id="footer">` with each element in a `<li>`, but attempting to style that with a `|` divider would be painful to do in a compliant and cross-browser fashion.

I would be happy with `a.`

Answer (score 3):

I would pick a for the first one. It is unlikely you will use more than one `h1`, plus that class name you chose ties presentation to the class name. You will have a problem, for example, if you want that changed to green at some time (the class name will be redundant).

For the footer, both look acceptable, depending on if you need that `p` as an extra hook for CSS.

I'd probably use the `p` anyway, as it is *paragraph-ish*.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you feel about [Is it alright to use multiple h1 tags on the same page, but style them differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503925/is-it-alright-to-use-multiple-h1-tags-on-the-same-page-but-style-them-differentl), you would pick answer a instead of answer e for Q1.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**  I would choose A.  It gives semantic meaning to the fact that it *is* a title.  An extra class is unnecessary because it's very specific to the current layout and/or design of the page.

**Question 2:**  Go with A.  A paragraph tag is inappropriate because the text contained in the footer is not actually a paragraph of text.  Real paragraphs contain at least one sentence and have a single idea or topic; what the example uses is just a short snippet of information, and isn't presented to the user as a paragraph.

Comment: I think question 2's answer is entirely subjective. Though you do make a good point not to use the `p`.

Comment: @alex I guess one could argue that the text deals with just the copyright info and is therefore a single idea, but I still don't think it's really a paragraph, like you'd see in a book, magazine, article, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 has been answered quite well above. The answer is (a), NOT (e).

For Q2, I'd personally do neither. Since `the text is arbitrary`, there's no way to mark-it-up semantically as we have no idea what the markup is trying to represent. However, assuming it is not directly related to the accompanying copyright notice, I would separate it in markup, as it IS separate. Something like:

```
<div id="footer">
  <small class="copyright">Copyright 2010 My Company</small> |
  <tagOfArbitraryMeaning>This text is arbitrary.</tagOfArbitraryMeaning>
</div>
```

(small might seem presentational, but "small-print" definitely has semantic meaning in my mind)

Or better yet:

```
<div id="footer">
  <a href="http://mycompany.website/copyrightinfo.html" rel="licence">Copyright 2010 My Company</a> |
  <tagOfArbitraryMeaning>This text is arbitrary.</tagOfArbitraryMeaning>
</div>
```

However, neither of those options are provided, so if I HAD to choose between the two, I'd probably go with (b), purely because it "feels" wrong to me to put text directly inside a `<div/>`, which is really designed to group other elements rather than to hold text directly.

`<div/>`s are intended purely for grouping other elements, as are other block-tags like `<blockquote/>` and `<fieldset/>`... Well - according to HTML4/XHTML1, this is how `<div/>`s should be used anyway - HTML5 has different ideas and has invented the `<section/>` element which does precisely the same thing `<div/>` used to do, while use of `<div/>` seems to be discouraged altogether... very odd.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in choosing e. for the first option, pending you will be using different kinds of h1 tags on the same page, but I would name your classes better. `align` is a somewhat deprecated HTML option that can be fulfilled using CSS. Also, avoid defining `style` within HTML tags. Ever.

For Q2, b is a better choice so that you can keep consistency throughout the site (such as with margins and padding set on

tags)