# Question about css hover

Tags: html, css

When mouse hover element 1 can i change css of element 2.

Here is an example:

```
<h1 id="text1">Text1</h1>
<h1 id="text2">Text2</h1>

#text1
{
    color:Green;
}

#text1:hover -> #text2  What i must write here??
{
    color:Red;
}

#text2
{
    color:Gray;
}
```

Comment: In general, why do you have 2 H1? Is it a table of contents? Otherwise you shouldn't have 2 H1s on a single page. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503925/is-it-alright-to-use-multiple-h1-tags-on-the-same-page-but-style-them-differentl/503949#503949

Answer (score 5):

you need to write `+`

```
#text1:hover+#text2 {
    color: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WG3rv/)

[w3 ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

**edit:**
in CSS3 there's a "[General sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)" (`~`) that can help you do the same even if the second header isn't immediately after the first -  **works in FF and Opera** (as tested so far)

html:

```
<h1 id="text1">text1</h1>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<h1 id="text2">text2</h1>
```

css:

```
#text1:hover ~ #text2 {
    color: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WG3rv/1/)

Comment: Note this doesn't work in IE6. Also, this selector is the adjacent selector: `#text1` must immediately precede `#text2`

Comment: I guess the IE6 support is neglectable. As @Dark Falcon mentions, just works in the (probably rare) case if the 2nd element is the immediate sibling.

Comment: @roberkules yes the second element has to immediately follow it, but in your specific case it will work

Comment: I'll be damned. Learn something new every day. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

```
#text1:hover + #text2
{
    color:Red;
}
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nxyfb/)

Comment: It's a good idea to read the existing answers before writing a new one