# whats the correct approach to this css

Tags: html, css

I have a page where the main element is a document, in this case a privacy policy.

The privacy policy title is an `<h1>` with the rest of the headings following, `<h2>` etc.

At the side of the document, but not in the flow of the H1, I have a small submenu which also has a heading. The question is what should the heading tag be on that?

[image]

Although I'm using some html5 elements I'm not using SECTION etc, due to the reliance on javascript for older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this web page is part of a web site (and not a stand-alone document), you probably don't want to use `h1` for the main content heading.

Even if you don't use the sectioning elements (`section`, `article`, `aside`, `nav`), your headings still create an [outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/headings-and-sections.html#headings-and-sections). This outline should represent the structure of your page, similar to a ToC.

So let's think of a simple website with: a) site header, b) main content, c) site navigation

If you use `h1` for the heading of your main content, the site-wide header and the site-wide navigation would be in the scope of this main content:

1. Privacy Policy

   1. My cool website
   2. Navigation

But this is not correct. "Privacy Policy" is part of "My cool website", not the other way around. And "Navigation" is not a sub-part of "Privacy Policy". So your outline should look like:

1. My cool website

   1. Privacy Policy
   2. Navigation

So the solution is: use `h1` for your site-wide heading (typically the name of your company/project/person/etc.). All scopes of your page are "dominated" by this heading. This is what unites your pages to a site.

Note: if you would use sectioning elements, you could use `h1` for each sectioning content.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **h3** according to WordPress widget-titles that are also h3

e.g.

```
<h3 class="widget-title srp-widget-title">
    POPULAR ARTICLES
</h3>
```

I would stay away from h1 and h2 in widgets(sidebars). If it is h3 or h4 doesn't matter too much... imho.

Comment: i do agree with Derfder, it is important to have only 1 H1 tag into your website page. h3 tag can be used multiple time !!

Comment: "not if you are using header-groups" clarify your statement, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a H1 tag, contrary to popular belief you don't get penalized for multiple H1 tags; however it may have some effect on the SEO of your site.

For confirmation you can browse the articles below:

[Is it alright to use multiple h1 tags on the same page, but style them differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503925/is-it-alright-to-use-multiple-h1-tags-on-the-same-page-but-style-them-different)

http://www.seomoz.org/q/multiple-h1-tags-on-same-page

And most importantly, the below link offers an interesting read:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/kYX4Upa8_es

Snippet from the link above of particular interest:

> When google is 'allocating' weight to a page, one of the factors is
>   the text found inside your H tags.
>
> So if you have one H1 tag, and not much text in it, google will see
>   this as 'very strong text' with lots of meaning. If you have one H1
>   tag for a whole paragraph of text, google will see this as 'weak text'
>   due to the total number of words contained inside the H1 tag.
>
> The number of H1 tags on a page also affects this, if you have two H1
>   tags, this 'very strong text' weight will be halved, if you have
>   three, it will be (well, I'm not sure if it's a third of the original
>   weight, or reduced by a factor of three (ie, original weight divided
>   by two, and then divided by two again)) and so on. So having many H1
>   tags is a bad idea because you will have more combined text inside H1
>   and it also gets divided by the number of H1 tags on the page.
>
> As for what happens in HTML5, sorry, but I'm not sure how google views
>   this nested syntax, I just wanted to expand and clarify on what
>   Cristina was talking about.

Although if you're really paranoid about SEO just stick a H3 in there, I'm sure it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

because of each heading tag  indicates the relative importance of each section, so it's best to start with the highest level header and work you way down. I would put it in h3

Answer (score 0):

It is considered a heading, so it should probably be `<h3>`.

Answer (score -1):

if there are no `<h3>` in the main content, then use a `<h3>` in the sidebar.
If you want to see it as e new content, use `<h1>` again.

It really depends on the context you see it, or your UX'er.