# Style elements or use classes?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know what is more correct, if I have say FOUR types of headings on my page.

Is it ok to just use `h1, h2, h3, h4` and style those elements?

OR is it better to just use the `<p>` or `<div>` element for each heading and make a class for each type of heading?

Is it best to use the second approach regardless, or should I only bother using the second approach (using classes) only if I had say NINE different headings?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `h1`-`h6` for headings and also there are 6 headings, for 9, you can use `p` or `div` if the sizes differ for last 3

Comment: @Mr.Alien is right. `p` is good option as each `p` starts with a new line like `h` without efforts, as you are new to this world.

Comment: Thank you guys this is good advice I would tick this but I don't think this was an answer, only a comment?

Comment: It depends on your needs. For example you have a template and you change `h1` `h2` ... for your template usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NZGamma please use h1 to h6 for heading.and it helping for SEO.

```
"The six heading elements, H1 through H6, denote section headings. Although the order and occurrence of headings is not constrained by the HTML DTD, documents should not skip levels (for example, from H1 to H3), as converting such documents to other representations is often problematic. W3C"
```

and use p for paragraph and like that...

Link : http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/

Link :http://webdesign.about.com/od/seo/a/why_use_h1_for_seo.htm

Comment: Thank you for the links, great information for me. So just to confirm; the second link says how important h1 is for SEO - but is it ok to use multiple h1's with different content in them on my site?

Comment: Hi it is possible to have multiple H1 because several H1s depends on  your content. have look this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503925/is-it-alright-to-use-multiple-h1-tags-on-the-same-page-but-style-them-different

Answer (score 0):

you can do both:

```
h2{
 color:red;
 font-size:12px;
}
```

or

```
h3{
 color:blue;
}


  <h2>Hello</h2>  //will be red and 12px
  <h3>GoodBye</h3> //will be blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Using heading tags are best beacause these are w3c standard for headings.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5

Comment: I would still only need to change the css styling for heading1 once though. Maybe I didn't phrase my question correctly; I just wanted to learn if it was perfectly ok to style the headings or if I should style them using p and class :)

Comment: If you sure want to apply only headings like h1, h2, ... then you should use h tags, because these are standard for headings.